# How to make sortable a DataGrid bounded with a table

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, sorting, datagridview

I load data on a DataGrid from a SQLite database with code like this:

```
conn.Open()
Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM TableDataGrid"
Dim cmdConnection As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(sql, conn)

Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter
da.SelectCommand = cmdConnection

Dim dt As New DataTable
da.Fill(dt)
MyDataGrid.DataSource = dt
```

When the user click on a Row I display the data on a few textbox, combobox, no problem at all.

Now I need to let the user sort the DataGrid by clicking the column he want and of course is not that simple.

After research on the "e.RowIndex >= 0"  and "System.NullReferenceException" error I understand that "The problem is that out of the box the BindingList does not support sorting! I know - sounds dumb but that is how it is." posted here: [WinForms: DataGridView - programmatic sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700782/winforms-datagridview-programmatic-sorting)

So If I'm right I need to implement my own SortableBindingList but I'm confused because the samples of code are about a LIST and I load the database records on a TABLE (dt)

Example:
http://timvw.be/2007/02/22/presenting-the-sortablebindinglistt/

Another post say I can fix the trouble with a line like:

```
SortableBindingList<YourListType> sortableBindingList = new SortableBindingList<YourListType>(list)
```

**What is the generic solution to make the DataGrid sortable on this case?**

Comment: Create a `DataView` from the `DataTable` and then apply filter to DataView. The set the Data Source to your view...

Comment: If your `DataGrdiView` is bound to a `DataTable`, it is already sortable: if the user clicks on a column header, the display will sort by that column.  To do it programmatically, you should hold onto your datatable: `myDT.DefaultView.Sort = "COLUMN_NAME Asc"`

Comment: @Zaggler The lines `Dim dt As New DataTable
da.Fill(dt)
MyDataGrid.DataSource = dt` are not doing that? I mean, create a DataView from the DataTable?

Comment: @Plutonix I think the DataGridView is bound to a DataTable with the line `MyDataGrid.DataSource = dt` but when the user clicks on a column header I get a message "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Program.exe but was not handled in user code" I think is becuase the row - 1 thing but I don´t know how to fix it.

Comment: Where do you get the error - what event?  You dont need any code at all in any event whatsoever to implement the sort - it does it by itself

Comment: I get the error on the sub `Private Sub MyDataGrid_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyDataGrid.SelectionChanged` It's the same Sub where I implemented the code to show the datagrid row on various textbox, combox. That part is working when I click on a Row with Data. I get the error when I click on the headers

Comment: Without the code, we can only guess.  It probably has to do with the selected index or code assuming something about the number of items selected.  The post mentions `e.RowIndex` but that is not available in the `SelectionChanged` event

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127493/discussion-between-fedeteka-and-plutonix).

Comment: Sorry, I cant do chat

Comment: @Plutonix No problem, I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the tips of the users I found the solution

```
 Private Sub MyDataGrid_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyDataGrid.SelectionChanged

    'Check if the user clicked on a header or a row

    Try
        If MyDataGrid.CurrentRow.Index = Nothing Then
            'Header clicked!! 
        Else
            'Row clicked!!!
            'Here I load the data of the clicked row on my form
            FormCleanDataEntry()
            FormShowRowData()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        'MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try

End Sub
```

**The curiosity is that the exception is thrown but anyway I don't show any message to the user and the DataGrid is sorted and the program works fine**

Comment: a) Swallowing exceptions  is a bad idea; b) you almost always want to compare to `Nothing` using `Is`; if it wont compile you are doing the wrong thing. That comparison test isnt doing what you think.  I dont know what that code does but firing from  `SelectionChanged` seems a bad idea because it is fired too often.  For instance, when the data is sorted the selected rows are reset.  I should think something where you can positively discern the user's intent would be better - like when they double click the row header.

Comment: (You can also assign context menus to the DGV or even by column)

Comment: @Plutonix I will try with the double click idea, but then I need to avoid single click on the header.

Comment: I am not sure why that is but it was just a suggestion,  You cold also add a button column or a context menu or a form button to "Foo Selected Row(s)" (again I dont know what the code is supposed to do exactly)

Comment: When the user click on a Row I display all the info of the selected Row on individuals texbox, combobox and radio buttons so the user can Edit and Update the record easily. The option of sort the grid by the selected column is just for make it easy the location of the records

Comment: If the DGV is using a DataTable as a DataSource records can be edited right there - the DGV will help enforce data validation elements like string length for a column defined as Varchar(15) or only allow valid dates.  That means no code to move data from DGV to controls and then back when they are done.  If you save the DataAdapter, no code to update the db other than `myDA.Update(myDT)`

Comment: "If the DGV is using a DataTable as a DataSource records can be edited right there" I know but I can´t do that on my case. The DGV is a linear version of a normalized database. Example: The user Michael can have various cars: Ford, VW, Toyota. On the database there's one record for every car of the user so I can keep records of the model, colour, and so on. When I display the DGV I combine all the cars name and just display something like "Ford | VW | Toyota" hidding all the other details. When the user click on that row then I decombine all the info on the form for individual edition