# DataGridView sorting on column header click when sort mode set to not sortable

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that has all columns sort mode set to not sortable. However, when I click on the column header. It changes the order? How can I prevent this? My DGV is unbound and virtual mode is set to true if that makes any difference?

Comment: VirtualMode does make the difference. Do you really need it?

Answer (score 0):

You may overwrite:

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
```

more You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700782/winforms-datagridview-programmatic-sorting):